# Bing Maps not displaying properly on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, bing-maps

I have used Bing Maps onto my website, in which I used Script

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    var map = null;
    function LoadMap() {


        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(
            document.getElementById('bing_maps_content'),
            {
                credentials: ".............."
            });
    }



    $('#btnlocation').click(function () {
        var url = "/Home/getlocation";

        $.getJSON(url, null, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, LocationData) {

                var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), null);

                pushpin.setLocation(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(
                   LocationData.longitutde,
                   LocationData.latitude
                   ));

                map.entities.push(pushpin);

                map.setView({
                    zoom: 4, centre: new Microsoft.Maps.Location("-37.81633","144.97097")
                });


        });
    });


    });
    LoadMap();
});

$(".jump-response").each(function () {
    var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor((256 - 199) * Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256 - 199) * Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256 - 199) * Math.random()) + 200) + ')';
    $(this).css("background-color", hue);
});
```

and loaded the data using controller and Model using Microsoft Bing map tutorial C# MVC . It works fine but when displayed onto my website it becomes like this.

[image]

It's displaying these diamond white shapes even if I zoom in. How do I get rid of these covering the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lol, wow, that is impressive. In the 9+ years I have been working with Bing Maps I have never seen that before.

Ok, now onto solving the issue. The code you provided won't cause this effect. It looks like each circle consists of a single map tile which is nothing more than an image tag. I suspect that somewhere in your application you have a CSS style for images that gives them a large border radius in order to make them look like circles. This style appears to be applied to all images in your app. Take a look at your CSS and look for any definitions on the img tag.

Comment: You're a genius, thank you very much for the help, it turns out it was one of my css properties that was hidden in another folder.